# Writing to one file from two threads produces unexpected result

Tags: java

When I run this test

```
public class Test extends Thread {
    String str;

    Test(String s) {
        this.str = s;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("1.txt", true);
            for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
                System.out.print(c);
                fw.write(c);
            }
            fw.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new File("1.txt").delete();
        new Test("11111111111111111111").start();
        new Test("22222222222222222222").start();
    }
}
```

it shows exactly how it writes characters to 1.txt

```
2222222222222222111211111211111121211111
```

but in 1.txt I see a different result

```
2222222222222222222211111111111111111111
```

why is that?

Comment: This is because file writes using FileWriter are delayed but not the console outputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Intermediate buffers. Usually modern OS buffer file writes to write full sectors at once, to avoid too much hard-drive header seeks, allow use of DMA techniques, etc...

Answer (score 0):

This may be an example of **ASYNC I/O Write**.

The kernel updates the corresponding process(different) pages in the page-cache and marks them dirty(needs to be updated in HDD). Then the control quickly returns to the corresponding process (here 2 different processes) which can continue to run and update in the console in the order called by the scheduler. The data is flushed to HDD later at a more optimal time(low cpu-load) in a more optimal way(sequentially bunched writes). and hence writes from process area sequentially.